# RainMaker to WordPress Import

Tags: wordpress

I am in process of migrating my website from Rainmaker to WordPress. I have data in xml file but when I am importing into wordpress, I am getting an error "Failed to import “Sales Page”: Invalid post type landing_page"

All the content that I am migrating is under a tab called Landing Page in RainMaker.

Any help would be great.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to start with creating the custom post type for this and again try to migrate

```
add_action( 'init', function () {
    register_post_type( 'landing_page', [
        'public' => true,
        'labels' => [
            'singular_name' => 'LandingPage',
            'name'          => 'LandingPage',
        ]
    ]);
});
```